# Will a CRON job be suitable for this?

Tags: php, database, email, cron

I have a database with an email address, an interval of how often someone wants an email sent to them (ranges from every 5 minutes to every couple of days) and the time at which an email was last sent. I currently have a PHP script that runs through the database and finds times before the current time and sends them an email and updates the time at which it is scheduled send the new email (using the interval).

Would it be OK to set this script up as a CRON job and run it every say 4 minutes? Or would this create too much overhead? I have 500+ tuples of data that it will need to traverse every 4 minutes.

Comment: Who would want to get an email every 5 minutes?

Comment: I suppose that sending an email that frequently you want to get voted "mr popularity"

Comment: If you have to ask then you probably need to learn a little more about cron jobs, and also explore your options. Personally, I would write a program (probably in Go, but most languages would do) that only does what you describe, and does it well. Using cron jobs to spin up a PHP script at some interval may work, but it is a little iffy, if you ask me.

Comment: CRON is good. Using standard tools which can be _configured_ is far better software practice than manually hard-coding something that can't be. PHP is pretty rubbish, but it's what he's using and (if you don't mind working around it's poor security & gaping holes) will do the job.

Comment: @RUJordan While I appreciate you took your time to comment, it is unnecessary. This is what the client has asked for, so this is what I am delivering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't send anyone an email unless they have requested it specifically or your sever will be black listed for spam and no emails will get through.
Second, a cron job is perfect for that kind of job. If the maximum rate is one email every 5 minutes there would be an average of 100 emails every **1 minute** cron run (if everyone for some mind boggling reason did decide to have an email that frequently)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a good candidate for a CRON job. No, it's not too much *processing overhead* to run this every 4 minutes. You should use SQL to query only those rows that may need an email, and running such a query should take about 25 ms.

But from a business perspective, once per day (every 24 hours) or a few times per day should be sufficient & indeed preferable. As the commenter above said.